# Get-ADUser and export only user objects to CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

I have the following code to export user from `Get-ADuser` to csv file:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $TargetOU -Properties * |
    Select EmailAddress |
    Sort EmailAddress |
    Export-Csv "C:\Temp\O365Migration\UserMigration#1.csv" -NoType
```

This works fine but does add blank rows to the exported file where groups or OUs are present in the target OU. I'm assuming these object types can be filtered out by using the -Filter parameter but have tried adding the below will no change in output.

```
-Filter {ObjectClass -eq "user"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess would be that it is users w/o an emailaddress in the AD.

`... getOU -Properties * | Where-Object {$_.EmailAddress -ne "" -OR $_.EmailAddress -ne $null} | Select-Object EmailAddress | ...`

Comment: Nice one thanks Jonas. Using this basis I'd expect any distribution groups to still be picked up seeing as they do have an email address present but appears not. Also I'm now trying to exclude users which have already been processed which will have a new UPN suffix so tried -or $_.UserPrincipalName.Split('@')[1] -notlike "newdomain.com"} but doesn't exclude these users. Am I missing something?

Comment: @jshizzle `Get-ADUser` adds the following filter clauses to the underlying ldap filter when querying AD: `(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))`, so it will never return distribution groups

Comment: Ok, that does may sense and so in that case shouldn't return OU objects either. The first couple of rows of my CSV file were blank so wonder what was causing these then!? Adding the where clause above gets rid of them however!

Comment: Obviously there were user accounts without an email address. `Get-ADUser ... | ? { -not $_.EmailAddress } | select -Expand distinguishedName` should reveal who they are.

Comment: Oh dear I am sorry for that. You're spot on [Facepalm]. Any idea how I can filter out already processed users based on the UPN suffix?

Comment: Ignore that, I was using -or instead of -and. Using the latter works as desired. Should fully test before asking.